# page gets scrolled to top when absolute positioned drop down is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have notification drop down just like that of facebook. when clicked on link, this drop down is shown, which is positioned as absolute. problem is, when the drop down is opened, the page is getting scrolled to top. Unfortunately I cant paste code as its huge. can you guess what could be the problem.

Ok here is what I have. http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/uuQf3/1/
first scroll down then click on black link, and see that, it scrolls up first then shows notification drop down.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with a smaller amount of code then. Take out the irrelevant parts, and see if it still happens.

Comment: And if it still does happen, add the code here or somewhere for us to see and interact with it.  Also, check the anchor tag `<a>`, does it have a `href="#"`? If so, you need to return false with the javascriptfunction that is called on the clickevent.

Comment: @wsanville I have edited with my code

Comment: @HenrikAmmer I have edited, check the code now.

Comment: @HenrikAmmer you are right. I added return false, and it worked... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above said, anchor tag with # href attribute will take you to the top of page, the solution to this is

catch the onclick event and do this

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   //OR
  return false;

});
```

this will restrict its default behavior.

or you can directly write it in your anchor element like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that your link is trying to find an anchor tag called #. This doesnt exist, so it scrolls to the top of the page. What you need is to tell the event handler to not do the default action of loading the href="#".

The solution is to add `e.preventDefault()` to your event handler.

See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ksokhan/uuQf3/2/